# require('react-native').NativeModules.RNRandomBytes is null

Tags: typescript, react-native, npm

In the index.js of the npm library react-native-randombytes there's a line: `let RNRandomBytes = require('react-native').NativeModules.RNRandomBytes`. In the `init()` method there's a code block wrapped in an if statement, `if (RNRandomBytes.seed) { ... }`, and here's where the code is breaking, as `RNRandomBytes` is undefined.

In debugging, I've found that `NativeModules` has plenty of libraries associated with it, just not `RNRandomBytes`. I'm in a Windows 10 environment, using node.js and react-native via rn-nodeify. I've gone through the react-native-crypto steps, including the `react-native link` step. I'm guessing I'm missing something, is there a way to populate `NativeModules` with `RNRandomBytes`?

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuild your ios/android code.

If you install a new package which includes native code, you need to rebuild your native code. The hot reload in react-native is just loading the js and assets files.

Comment: I'm not building it for ios or android, I'm in a windows environment. That is to say, I technically have index.ios.js and index.android.js, but I don't use them, I'm only focused on index.windows.js. My dev process involves transpiling, calling react-native bundle, and then running. Is there some step I'm missing to completely rebuild the thing?

Answer (score 0):

That's where native modules can be found when they're registered on the native side. The issue here is that there's currently no native windows implementation of that package.

Update: I double-checked and it turns out there's an open PR to add Windows UWP app support, try that fork:
`npm i --save https://github.com/newomble/react-native-randombytes`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had react-native-randombytes installed. Maybe you did the `react-native link` or `react-native link react-native-randombytes` as me. I opened podfile and it did link for us. However, if you opened pod.lock and looked for it, it did not auto install for us. I went to ios folder and `pod install`, it finally works. this issue wasted me like 5 days.